# Form object in the console gets deleted on submit

Tags: javascript, html

This is my form and I am trying to output the submitted details as an object. The doubt I have is how can I prevent the form from submitting when fields are empty? I want to check whether all the functions above `validate()` is true or not and then execute the validate function if not true, prevent the form from submitting. The errors that are shown stays there in the form even after submission. I have tried to refresh the window using `window.location.reload()` but then the object I want is lost by this method. Is there any way I can achieve this?

```
x = "correct"


function nameValidate(value) {
    namev = value;
    if (namev.length <= 3) {
        
        var nameError = "Enter a valid name"
        document.getElementById("nameerror").innerHTML = nameError
        //return 1;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("nameerror").innerHTML = x
        //return 0;
    }

}

function emailValidate(value) {
    emailv = value;
    if (emailv.length < 5) {
        var emailError = "Enter a valid email"
        document.getElementById("emailerror").innerHTML = emailError
        //return 1;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("emailerror").innerHTML = x
        //return 0;
    }

}

function companyValidate(value) {

    if (value === "") {
        var companyError = "Enter a valid company";
        document.getElementById("companyerror").innerHTML = companyError;
        //return 1;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("companyerror").innerHTML = x;
        //return 0;
    }

}

function phoneValidate(value) {
    phonev = value;
    if ( phonev.length !== 10 ) {
        var phoneError = "Enter a valid 10 digit phone number";
        document.getElementById("phoneerror").innerHTML = phoneError;
        //return 1;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("phoneerror").innerHTML = x;
        //return 0;
    }

}

function validate(e) {

    /* Variables for field values and form */
    var name=document.getElementById("name").value;
    var email=document.getElementById("email").value;
    var company=document.getElementById("company").value;
    var phone=document.getElementById("phone").value;
    var desc=document.getElementById("description").value;
    var project=document.getElementById("project").value;
    var form = document.getElementById("form");
    
    //e.preventDefault();   
    console.log({name,email,company,phone,desc,project});
    form.reset();
 }

 //form.addEventListener("submit",validate(),true);
```

Comment: Use `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: If you change ```//e.preventDefault();``` in your code to ```e.preventDefault();``` it should stop the refresh.

To prevent the form from submitting with any empty inputs, you can simply add ```required``` to the ```input``` tag in your HTML, like ```<input type="text" required>```

Comment: how can I write the function `validate(e)` to prevent this since I want to check the above functions return true or not?